# Why is my .Net 6 API throwing a 302 on HTTP redirect rather than a 307, changing my POST to a GET?

Tags: https, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-307

I have one web API I essentially copied from another. Both have `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` as well as `app.UseHSTS()` in their `Program.cs`. Both have Swagger redirect working (this is a local internal test site).

However, when I use Postman to try to fetch the original token, the original Web API returns a 307 and redirects the POST, but the other one returns a 302 and redirects to GET:

```
POST http://webapicore-dev.calfee.com/token 307  

POST https://webapicore-dev.calfee.com/token 200

POST http://recordsapps-dev.calfee.com/token 302

GET https://recordsapps-dev.calfee.com/token 405
```

Comment: There has to be difference between 2 projects. How can same projects act differently? Such as the depoly enviroment?

Comment: @QiangFu - I agree!  I just can't seem to find any. I have looked at all the code between the two APIs, they are not only on the same server but in the same folder.

Comment: Is the port number also the same?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the IIS setup and they seem to be exactly the same.